# VSCODE Gitlens Undo Merge Manually

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge, gitlens

While merging manually using vscode-gitlens command --no-ff, I just notice i'm trying to merge SIT to my file and now it stucks at this stage where I cant undo the changes. Can anyone provide any solution on how to undo/revert? or I need to commit and push first then only can revert it. Thanks

[Gitlens Merge ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSxp7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

open the terminal and type

`git reset --hard HEAD`